# How can i convert my geometry column to unify all my polygons?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

Hello I just start to work with postgis,

I need to do those differents steps :

1. from my geometry column create circle with a radius of 500m
2. create polygon
3. with the polygon created I want to unify them all (i have a lot of data)
4. transform them in geojson

I show u all my try :

```
select geography(st_transform(geom::geometry,4326),500) from table

select ST_polygon(geom::geometry,2154) from table

select st_union(geom::geometry) from table

select cast ( geom as geography) from table
```

Nothing work

**UPDATE**

my geom value look like this
[image: geom_value]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in a single query. First create a buffer with `ST_Buffer` casting the geometry to geography, so that it accepts metres as unit. After that, aggregate the just created polygons with `ST_Collect` or `ST_Union`, then finally use `ST_AsGeoJSON` to display the multipolygon as GeoJSON:

```
SELECT 
  ST_AsGeoJSON(
    ST_Union(
      ST_Buffer(
        ST_Transform(geom,4326)::geography,
        500)::geometry))
FROM t;
```

Note: the `ST_Transform(geom,4326)` is necessary as the geometry's CRS is a *non lon/lat* one, and therefore cannot be directly cast to `geography`. Transforming it in query time to i.e. WGS84 does the trick.

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=509cbb75ef99989cf9e058ec3214d987)

Comment: I get this error 

> ERROR:  ERREUR:  Only lon/lat coordinate systems are supported in geography

Comment: @user10863293 what is the SRID of your coordinates?

Comment: i update to show u my geom value and when i do st_srid(geom) i have `2154`

Comment: @user10863293 check my last edit: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=509cbb75ef99989cf9e058ec3214d987

Comment: I just have a question so even if I have a lot of datas my field will show all of them or i have a field value limit ?

Comment: @user10863293 this query will create one buffer per geometry on the table, and in the end all buffers will be inside a multipolygon serialised as geojson.